# How to create a simple website with some player which buffers videos

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I am aware of Apache, HTML5 video, but have very minimal knowledge in domain of video streaming/buffering/encoding.

I want to create an application which would stream some stored video files and there should be buffering on the client side. I am unsure how that can be accomplished. Is some special handling on web server side and/or client side needed to accomplish this?

I'd really request you to be elaborate with your answers.

### EDIT 1

I read that nginx and apache can stream mp4 and flv video files. So do they support the buffering and seek capability as well?

### EDIT 2

I am only interested in creating some thing that can work on crome desktop browser, no need to make it work on all the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the edits.

> I read that nginx and apache can stream mp4 and flv video files. So do
>   they support the buffering and seek capability as well?

For HTTP delivered video, this is a client side feature. As long as the server handles HTTP/1.1 byte ranges you can use whatever http server you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have basic question, for such HTTP delivered video, is there option to buffer also on the client side?

Comment: Thats up to the client

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jwplayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) to get started for video streaming. If you are using a media server or popular CDN's to host your videos, RTMP streaming is automatically suppported, otherwise it will be progressive (buffering) downnload

Comment: So if lets say I use nginx+rtmp plugin, would I be able to use buffering on jwplayer?

Comment: I may be asking for too much, but is there a blog which details some such example? I'm sure this is a very common usecase, still I can't find one

Comment: Take a look here http://support.jwplayer.com/ . There are lot of tutorials to get you started.

Comment: I'll do that Mahesh. Just let me know if ngingx+rtmp plugin and jwplayer, is this good enough for what I'm going for?

Comment: give it a shot and see how it goes

Comment: I read that nginx and apache can be used to serve mp4 and flv for streaming. So do they provinde the buffer and seek capability?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to play the video in chrome you can use the mp4 file with Apache/Nginx or any other http server there is no need for a plugin.

You can use an html5 player take a look at [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) it also supports seek and pause.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to simply use HTML5 video. Just to stream a video, the HTML5 video player will work fine. Encode your video in mp4 format, make sure you use H.264 video codec for your encoding, it will work perfectly. All you need to do is to put this in your Html:

```
<video controls poster="images/some_image.jpg">
<source src="your_folder/your_video_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you want to dig deeper into video streaming issues with HTML5 you can check this link here: [More stuff about HTML5 Video](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)